# IP address of a machine

Tags: java, sockets, networking, datagram

I have

#### UDP client and UDP server program written in java

. I am sending an xml to udp server and waiting for response from udp server. So in xml I am sending IP address of client and port no on which udp client is listening. I am able to send xml to udp server and udp server is also able to receive that  But my problem is udp client is not able to receive response as IP address of UDP client is wrong.

#### So help me to get IP address of udp client so that i can send it to server in xml.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't follow. What IP do you expect and get? How have you been obtaining the client IP? Remember that the client might be behind a NAT.

Comment: This could very well be a NAT related issue indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to send your own IP address.

The peer knows where the datagram came from, via the address/port parameters of DatagramPacket.

All the peer has to do is rewrite the data part of the DatagramPacket and send() it. It will go back back where it came from.